# How to pass bearer token in SOAP client request

Tags: c#, authorization, soap-client, bearer-token

I am making call to SOAP based API. I need to pass a bearer token for Authorization. But I am unable to figure out how to pass it.

Below is how I make API call

```
SoapServiceClient cs = new SoapServiceClient (); //initializing SoapHttpClientProtocol
cs.Timeout = 99999999; 
cs.Url = "https://gateway.client.com/v1"; //API endpoint
object response = cs.CreateSession(createSessionRequest); //Calling one of its API and assigning the response xml in response object. CreateSession is client's method in wsdl.

//how to set bearer token, something like below:
cs.Authorization = "Bearer" + generatedtoken;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about it. I followed [this document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/soap-web-service-in-net-core/) to create a SOAP web service in .net 7, then I can get the API response from postman like below.

[image]

Then I tried to use httpClient to call it in the .net 7 web application. And I found I'm able to get the response. Then I noticed that in .net 5+, we have [corewcf which supports Http & NetTCP transports](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/corewcf-v1-released/).

[image]

Comment: Will this work if i am consuming wsdl and its methods?

Comment: it depends on the .net version if you are having them in a .net core project. because all my test is based on corewcf and SoapCore. just have a try to see if it worked for you, if  not, then update here and see others' suggestions.